# Запуск программы в gdb

Tags: linux, отладка, g++

Есть такая проблема: запускаю консольную программу `test` через gdb и она нормально работает. Если запускаю программу через консоль `./test` то программа стабильно падает с ошибкой `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

Как эту программу отлаживать? В чем отличие запуска через `gdb` и через консоль? Может быть есть какие либо флаги у `gdb` для такого случая?

Comment: **стабильно падает.** - и что это значит? Хотя бы текст сообщения об ошибке можно было привести?

Comment: Код-то приведите. 99% таких случаев связано с очень простыми ошибками, типа неинициализированных переменных.

Comment: **В чем отличие запуска через gdb и через консоль?** - в содержимом памяти. У Вас где-то используется не инициализированная память. При запуске под *gdb* там оказывается что-то "приемлемое", а при запуске из командной строки - что-то совсем другое.

Comment: Падает с ошибкой `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` Программа довольно большая и свести ее к минимуму не получается именно потому что я не знаю  где ошибка.

Comment: Программа многопоточная? Я бы ставил на гонку... С учётом того что «(core dumped)» — для начала загрузи корку в gdb и посмотри где падает...

Comment: **Segmentation fault** означает неинициализированный указатель.  Первое, что надо сделать -  понять в какой функции происходит падение. Для этого задайте в программе обработчик сигнала SIGSEGV и в нём распечатайте стек вызовов с помощью стандартной функции backtrace.

Comment: После того, как с функцией определились - внимательно просмотрите её текст на предмет использования указателей. В 3/4 случаев можно отловить ошибку просто изучая код. Если не получилось, перед **каждым** использованием указателя поставьте нечто вроде *if(pointer == NULL) { Печать сообщения об ошибке }*

Comment: Разобрался с проблемой, это действительно была гонка потоков

Comment: @Sergey, откуда такая уверенность про неинициализированную память? Это только один вариант, который может привести к падению.

Comment: @0andriy - да, могут быть и другие причины. Но в 99% - так. Дело в том, что написать* ptr =  1; можно запросто (при не инициализированном ptr), а вот написать  нечто вроде array[-5] = 1; значительно сложнее.